# FIrebase message content not recieving

Tags: android, firebase, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am getting notification but i cant get the notification body  from notification .
I have created a firebase service class and added  the dependencies(    compile `'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.6'`) and edited manifest(

```
<service
                android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
                </intent-filter>
            </service>)
```

what might be the reason ?

```
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage;

public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    private static final String TAG = "FCM Service";
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        // TODO: Handle FCM messages here.
        // If the application is in the foreground handle both data and notification messages here.
        // Also if you intend on generating your own notifications as a result of a received FCM
        // message, here is where that should be initiated.
        Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());
        Log.d(TAG, "Notification Message Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    }
}
```

I am not getting any logs .

Comment: `I am getting notification but i cant get the notification body from notification` ???? there is no code to trigger the notifications.. How can you say that.. u r getting notification?

Comment: your app is foreground or background?

Comment: your app in background at that time onMessageReceived is not call because your notification is your system tray.

Comment: I wasnt aware about the  data message and display message feature.I was dealing with display message feature

Comment: your app is in foreground then you can received messae.

Answer (score 1):

**There are two types of FCM Messaging **

```
Display Messages: These messages trigger the onMessageReceived() callback only when your app is in foreground

Data Messages: Theses messages trigger the onMessageReceived() callback even if your app is in foreground/background/killed
```

**Dont foregt this service Add manifestfile**

```
<service
    android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
    </intent-filter>
</service>

<service
    android:name=".MyFirebaseInstanceIDService">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

**Add Internet Permision in your manifestfile**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: you can read data message related  https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options

Comment: @EdwinThomas you can received FCM token

Comment: i am getting success message but i am not reciving the notification .when i tried with data messaging? any helps?

Comment: yes 100% help first you can tell me two services add manifest file

Comment: i have added those. but no success

Comment: i used a **WakefulBroadcastReceiver** and  got it woked. thanks anyway...